# proving a set is bounded Metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show that given the metric space X= $(\mathbb{R}^{2}, d)$ where $d$ is the usual Euclidean metric that the set $D=\{(x,y): \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} <1\}$ is bounded.

I am using Rudin and it gives the following definition of bounded: "$E \subseteq X$ is bounded if there is a real number $M$ and a point $q \in X$ such that $d(p,q) < M$ for all $p \in E$"

I understand the definition, but am having trouble applying it. I take $M = 1$ and let $q \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $p \in D$. Then I need to show that $d(p,q) < 1$.

So let's say $p$ has coordinates $(p_{1}, p_{2})$ and $q$ has coordinates $(q_{1}, q_{2})$. Then $\sqrt{(p_{1} - q_{1})^{2} + (p_{2} - q_{2})^{2}}$

but now I am not sure how to get to the conclusion. I could expand out the terms and use the fact that since $p \in D, \sqrt{p_{1}^{2} + p_{2}^{2}} < 1.$ Not sure if that is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $q=(0,0)$. for any $p=(x,y) \in D$ we have $d((x,y), (0,0))=\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}} <1$ so $D$ is bounded.

Comment: Much easier than I was making it! Thank you.